# QGIS change raster tiles properties at once

Tags: qgis, raster, tiles

I have a set of several raster tiles and I need to change the properties of each one, by setting up a transparency for instance. I have found no other solution but changing properties of each one at a time... When I select all tiles by pressing ALT + click, the properties of the fisrt one only are modified. Is there a way to perform that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the Python Console of QGIS with this code:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas

nc = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = []
renderers=[]

n = nc.layerCount()

for i in range(n):
    layers.append(nc.layer(i))

for layer in layers:
    renderers.append(layer.renderer())

for renderer in renderers:
    renderer.setOpacity(0.1) #I used a too low value for a better 
                             #visualization at the Map Canvas

iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

For testing it, I loaded the same raster four times and ran the code.

Before running the code (opacity = 1, transparency = 0 in all layers):

[image]

After running the code, the opacity of all layers was established in 0.1 (transparency  = 0.9) at once:

[image]